# SQL Server equivalent of "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" Status to find "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR"

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm getting

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "fk_XXX_has_staff". The conflict occurred in database "XXX", table
>   "dbo.XXX", column 'XXX_id'"

I understand what the error is, but I want to determine what the FK is pointing to.

In MySQL, you can issue 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS' which will list out "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR". Is there an equivalent to this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

The error occur in your primary key table so you have to find values in insert which have no match in XXX_id column.

```
select t.* from
(values -- values to insert
(1,2),(1,3)) t(x,y)
left join dbo.XXX x on x.XXX_id = t.x
where x.XXX_id is null
```